# How do I split an integer up into near-equal amounts in different variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how to divide any given integer up into any given number of variables while ensuring that the total sum of the value in the variables don't amount to more than the initial integer value.

For example, I would like to divide 5 into 3 different variables, if I just do the below:

```
var1 = 5 / 3
var2 = 5 / 3
var3 = 5 / 3
```

I would get each value equating to 1.67 (rounded to 2 decimal places as it's a currency). However, if I was to then do 1.67 * 3 it equals more than 5. Where what I would like is variable 1 and 2 to be 1.67 and then the remaining variable would have the leftover value of 1.66.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Your suggestion to get three different numbers does not match the title. Either you want to get the closest repartition with a remaining in an acceptable appoximation range or you want to get equal amounts.

Comment: You suggestion does not make sense to me. If you intend to distribute equal amounts of money among people, why would you prejudice one of them?
Please reformulate the title if you are not looking for a equitable distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a general function that solves your problem.  It converts the `value` to `cents` and distributes them evenly into `nr_variables`, the remainder are put in the first variables until all spent.  The function returns a list of values.

```
def f(nr_variables, value):

    cents = value*100

    base = cents//nr_variables
    rem = int(cents%nr_variables)

    return [(base+1)/100]*rem + [base/100]*(nr_variables-rem)
```

this can be used like this:

```
f(3,5)
```

and gives:

[1.67, 1.67, 1.66]

if you want to assign the list to variables like you do in your question, you can do like this:

```
var1,var2,var3 = f(3,5)
```

Comment: This works for everything aside from values below 1. I've tried f(3, 0.5) and I get the following error ```in f
    return [(base+1)/100]*rem + [base/100]*(nr_variables-rem)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' ```

Comment: fixed to handle floats

Comment: note, has to be a valid currency (can't have 3 or more decimals)

Comment: Thanks, would the assignment of variables work for a list and dictionary ```var1, var2, var3 = f(3,5)```. I've got a dictionary with some values as "yes" and some "no". I'm trying to iterate through it with a for loop and then use an if v == "yes" statement to access the keys with a value equal to "yes" that I can then use as the variables for f().

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to loose precision in numbers, consider using Fraction:

```
from fractions import Fraction

var1 = Fraction(5, 3)
var2 = Fraction(5, 3)
var3 = Fraction(5, 3)

print(round(var1, 2))
print(round(var2, 2))
print(round(var3, 2))
print(var1 * 3)
```

result:

```
1.67
1.67
1.67
5
```

Comment: The question specifically says this is currency and needs to be rounded to two decimal places. So this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This answer applies to "how to divide a value into equal amounts".
Ask for a title refomulation if you don't want to consider it.

Comment: The title is *"How do I split an integer up into equal amounts in different variables?"* so I don't know where you got that from. The question also makes clear that the required outputs are 1.67, 1.67 and 1.66.

Comment: The title does not match the body of the question. I think my reformulation of the title is correct anyway.

Comment: If you think that makes the question unclear, then I would suggest asking for clarification from the OP before writing an answer. I think the question gives enough information to determine that fractions don't solve the problem; so whether or not the title should be edited, this still isn't a correct answer.

Comment: Apologies, having read the title again it is incorrect. As the body of the text says I do want to split it into "as equal amounts as is possible". I will amend the title, I think the function above is going to give me what I'm after. Thanks for the help

Comment: No worries. Now both question title and body match @Christian Sloper answer which is both right and efficient. I am still wondering if this algorithm is what you really want to achieve though. I wouldn't be the one that always have only the _remaining_ of the distributed money... I am editing my answer for a better match to that purpose. Maybe it will make more sense to you.