# Evenly divide a list of integers into a equal or larger list of integers with id's

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm looking to acheive this in Python 3.0, but I'm stuck on the math behind how to do it, rather than the code.

This question solves a little of the issue of (un)evenly splitting the value into a list in integers but does not address the other parts of the issue: [How do I split an integer up into near-equal amounts in different variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954891/how-do-i-split-an-integer-up-into-near-equal-amounts-in-different-variables)

I have an input such as:

```
{'apples':2,
'banannas':12,
'cats':5,
'dogs':7}

#User chooses value for N
N = 8
```

It is a dict with a variable amount of keys (Won't be more than 20 keys 99% of the time) and integer values. The values will always be positive integers.

I wish to evenly split the values into a list of length N (up to 17), such that every key input will be represented at least once in the output and every value will be as low integer as possible whilst still summing up to the input value.

If the output length N is less than the number of keys I will simply return an error.

The order of the output does not matter.

An example output for the given example with N = 4:

```
({'position': 1, 'type': 'apples', 'level': 2},
{'position': 2, 'type': 'banannas', 'level': 12},
{'position': 3, 'type': 'cats', 'level': 5},
{'position': 4, 'type': 'dogs', 'level': 7})
```

An example output for the given input with N = 7:

```
({'position': 1, 'type': 'apples', 'level': 2},
{'position': 2, 'type': 'banannas', 'level': 4},
{'position': 3, 'type': 'cats', 'level': 5},
{'position': 4, 'type': 'dogs', 'level': 4},
{'position': 5, 'type': 'banannas', 'level': 4},
{'position': 6, 'type': 'dogs', 'level': 3},
{'position': 7, 'type': 'banannas', 'level': 4})
```

At first I felt that the best idea would to make the initial list of dicts with N = len(input), then loop and add a new dict for whichever level is the highest, dividing the hoghest value by 2 to split it evenly but  in the second example output, I would have ended up with the type B's, I would have ended up with the levels 3,6,3 (Split the 12 into 6 & 6, then split 1 of the 6's into 3 & 3). Instead, if type b is to occupy 3 postions, each level should be the initial input divided by the positions it occupys (3).

In the case that an integer cannot be evenly split into however many integers, the difference between the max and min of the levels for that type should be equal to 1.

In each loop it should always be the highest output level type that is split.

Happy to clarify anything and answer questions.

Comment: `whilst still summing up to the input value` -- what is being summed? In your example 1 I see nothing that sums to the input `N` of 4.

Comment: The sum of 'levels' for each type in the output should be the input for it's type. N is the number of positions that will be in the output. I've edited the names of the types to make this slightly clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make max-heap data structure.

Fill it with K entries

```
{name; srclevel; divider; currentlevel}
```

for example:
{bananas, 12, 1, 12}

Key for heap ordering is `currentlevel`

Make `N-K` operations:

```
extract top entry
increase divider
recalculate currentlevel = ceil(srclevel / divider)
push changed entry into heap
```

example:

```
{bananas, 12, 1, 12} => {bananas, 12, 2, 6}
```

Now you have heap with N entries

Make resulting list. If some `divider` does not divide corresponding `srclevel`, fill `srclevel % divider` of values with `ceil(srclevel / divider)` and the rest - with  `floor(srclevel / divider)`

```
10 / 4 => 3, 3, 2, 2
```

Note that there is [heapq module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html) for Python. It implements min-heap, so to use it as max heap - just put negated currentlevel at the first place in element of heap (list or tuple).

```
import heapq

dict = {'apples':2,'banannas':12,'cats':5,'dogs':7}
N = 8
K = len(dict)

items = [(-value, value, 1, key) for key, value in dict.items()]
heapq.heapify(items)
for i in range(N-K):
    item = heapq.heappop(items)
    div = item[2] + 1
    heapq.heappush(items, (-((item[1] + div - 1)//div), item[1], div, item[3]))
print(items)

[(-4, 7, 2, 'dogs'), (-4, 12, 3, 'banannas'), 
 (-2, 2, 1, 'apples'), (-3, 5, 2, 'cats')]
```

We can see that bananas will be divided into three piles, dogs and cats - into two piles, apples remain in a single pile. 8 piles at all, size 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: I'm not able to code this rn and I'm unfamiliar with max heap data structures but from your explantion I reckon it'll work perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I added clues to implement in Python